# Naming complicated methods

Tags: c#, sql, database, sharepoint, methods

I have a method for pulling data from a database, and I want it to get this:

Limit of Five entries,
Item type is Newsletter,
Needs to be active (PublishDate < DateTime.Now)

So I'm thinking of naming it GetFiveActiveNewslettersByCreatedDate()

This seems a little long to me. I looked on the site for a good way to name things like this, how would you handle it?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that name, per se.  Alternatively you could have a method that takes in a max number to return as a parameter.

Comment: Hardcoding to 5 is a bad practice. I'd suggest you the following signature: `GetActiveNewsletters(int32 size)`

Comment: Further using `ByCreatedDate` is redundant, as `Active` already carries the meaning of the time predicate. If you'd use by `ByCreatedDate`, it'd imply that you are selecting with an additional predicate.

Comment: @Oybek Active was the condition for PublishedDate to be less than DateTime.now(). A Newsletter that was created with a PublishDate in the future would not want to be pulled.

Comment: This is what I mean. Even if nothing is changed `GetFiveActiveNewsletters` would suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid this specific naming I would think about making the method generic. Something like:

```
GetNewsLetters(int amount, bool onlyActive, SortOrder orderBy)
```

Answer (score 12):

How about something like this instead?

```
public IEnumerable<Newsletter> GetActiveNewsletters(int maxRecords = 5) 
{ 
    // ...
}
```

Top 5 is still the default, but it's not overly specific anymore.

Comment: I'd advise against public default parameters because they get compiled into the calling assembly, which can lead to subtle bugs if the called assembly is updated without recompiling and redeploying all callers.

Comment: @MichaelStum: Good point.  I guess it depends on the situation.  For many/most applications this is probably not an issue as it would be for something like a public API.

Answer (score 8):

The reason I would avoid baking "five" into the name, personally, is what it might mean down the line.

For example, what if later, there were some demand for 10 newsletters in certain scenarios instead of 5?  Well, you'd create an additional method `GetTenActiveNewslettersByCreatedDate()`.  And now, you have a 'design pattern' that subsequent developers will follow when 20, 50, 100 newsletters are needed.  This is a design that will rot, and you can stave it off now by parameterizing the five.

Of course, this might be YAGNI/speculative generality.  If 5 really is some kind of magic, hard-fast, will never change rule, then you might cautiously bake it in.  I just find that I've regretted doing and seeing things like that far, far more often than not.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend renaming it to: `GetNewsletters(int recordCount=5)`
The number of newsletters would be a parameter for the method.

The rest could be assumed and described in the `///Summary`.

Answer (score 2):

Name it so that it is evident to any developer what the method does. Self commenting code is king. If your method name gets too long, you're probably doing too many different things inside of it and would be a candidate for refactoring.

As for your specific example, I don't have a problem with the name you've given.

Answer (score 1):

I would add parametrized method, like

`GerEntries(T typeofEntity, DateTime date, int maxNumber)`

And naturaly document method with comments